# How to Mix Jade output with angular filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have an application that I'm converting from ejs template engine to jade.

in my ejs view I had this

```
<input class="form-control" value="{{<%=User.outlet.money%> | currency}}"   type="text" name="money" data-parsley-required="true"/>
```

pretty much converted my number output to a currency output.

In my jade app I have this

```
input.form-control(value= User.outlet.money, type='text', name='money')
```

I want something more like this.

```
input.form-control(value= {{User.outlet.money | currency}}, type='text', name='money')
```

How do I achieve the jade output to be filter by angular filters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/).

Example:

`input(value="{{#{User.outlet.money} | currency}}", type="text", name="money")`

for `User.outlet.money`==`2` the result will be:

`input(value="{{2 | currency}}", type="text", name="money")`